# How to serialize OBJECT ARRAY in java?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have an OBJECT ARRAY, how can i serialize this array? I give you c# code and i have to write in java. Thanks.
C#:

```
byte[] data = JSon.Serialize<object[]>(Parameters);
```

Please note that i want to serialize an array which has objects..
i realize that is not the exact answer:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(anyOutputStream);
out.writeObject(objectArray);
```

i have a problem with anyOutputStream, i really don't know what i should place on parameter..

Comment: I think it's already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262390/how-to-serialize-json-object-in-java

Comment: Use any of the existing JSON API's, for example [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Comment: Overview of JSON API's for Java [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object array contains Serializable objects then you can use java.io.ObjectOutputStream

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(anyOutputStream);
out.writeObject(objectArray);
...
```

Comment: i have error with "anyOutputStream".. i don't know what i should replace with

Answer (score 1):

`new JSONObject(parameters).toString().getBytes()`

requires JSONObject

Comment: i have this error message: The constructor JSONObject(Object[]) is undefined, any idea?

Comment: Clearly, you need a `JSONArray` if you're going to serialize an array. However, there's no guarantee it will work---it all depends on what the framework can do with your array elements.