# Jenkins Pipeline NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

**Solved**: Thanks to [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897833/3318642) from S.Richmond. I needed to unset **all** stored maps of the `groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` type which meant nullifying the variables `envServers` and `object` after use.

**Additional**: People searching for this error might be interested to use the Jenkins pipeline step `readJSON` instead - find more info [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).

---

I am trying to use Jenkins Pipeline to take input from the user which is passed to the job as json string. Pipeline then parses this using the slurper and I pick out the important information. It will then use that information to run 1 job multiple times in parallel with differeing job parameters.

Up until I add the code below `"## Error when below here is added"` the script will run fine. Even the code below that point will run on its own. But when combined I get the below error.

I should note that the triggered job is called and does run succesfully but the below error occurs and fails the main job. Because of this the main job does not wait for the return of the triggered job. I *could* try/catch around the `build job:` however I want the main job to wait for the triggered job to finish.

Can anyone assist here? If you need anymore information let me know.

Cheers

```
def slurpJSON() {
return new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(BUILD_CHOICES);
}

node {
  stage 'Prepare';
  echo 'Loading choices as build properties';
  def object = slurpJSON();

  def serverChoices = [];
  def serverChoicesStr = '';

  for (env in object) {
     envName = env.name;
     envServers = env.servers;

     for (server in envServers) {
        if (server.Select) {
            serverChoicesStr += server.Server;
            serverChoicesStr += ',';
        }
     }
  }
  serverChoicesStr = serverChoicesStr[0..-2];

  println("Server choices: " + serverChoicesStr);

  ## Error when below here is added

  stage 'Jobs'
  build job: 'Dummy Start App', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SERVER_NAME', value: 'TestServer'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SERVER_DOMAIN', value: 'domain.uk'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'APP', value: 'application1']]

}
```

Error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:569)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
...
...
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field delegate
    in field closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5288c
```

Comment: Just ran into this myself. Did you make any further progress yet?

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables

Comment: nice question - upvoted, but just a tip: you don't need to edit your question to link to the answer: that's what the checkmark is for (it also distracts from the highest-voted answer, which worked best for me)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I ran into this myself today and through some bruteforce I've figured out both how to resolve it and potentially why.

Probably best to start with the why:

Jenkins has a paradigm where all jobs can be interrupted, paused and resumable through server reboots. To achieve this the pipeline and its data must be fully serializable - IE it needs to be able to save the state of everything. Similarly, it needs to be able to serialize the state of global variables between nodes and sub-jobs in the build, which is what I think is happening for you and I and why it only occurs if you add that additional build step.

For whatever reason JSONObject's aren't serializable by default. I'm not a Java dev so I cannot say much more on the topic sadly. There are plenty of answers out there about how one may fix this properly though I do not know how applicable they are to Groovy and Jenkins. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25326211/420787) for a little more info.

How you fix it:

If you know how, you can possibly make the JSONObject serializable somehow. Otherwise you can resolve it by ensuring no global variables are of that type.

Try unsetting your `object` var or wrapping it in a method so its scope isn't node global.

Comment: Thanks, That's the clue I've needed to solve this. Whilst I had tried your suggesion already It made me look again and I hadn't considered that I was storing parts of the map in other variables - these were causing the errors. So I needed to unset them as well. Will amend my question to include the correct changes to the code. Cheers

Comment: This is viewed ~8 times a day.  Would you guys mind providing a more detailed example of how to implement this solution?

Comment: There is no simple solution as it depends on what you've done. The information provided here as well as the solution @Sunvic added at the top of his post aught to be enough to led one to a solution for their own code.

Comment: The solution below, using JsonSlurperClassic fixed the exact same issue I had, should probably be the approved choice here.  This answer has merits, but it's not the right solution for this particular problem.

Comment: @JordanStefanelli I posted the code for my solution. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53756295/1844551) below

Comment: No idea why this post still is a approved answer for this question. Though it gives the cause of the problem, it doesnt give the difference between LazyMap and HashMap (we assume are getting HashMap but we are getting not a thread safe lazyMap).  And so the error. Changing it to JsonSlurperClassic fixed my issue.

Comment: I was retrieving the Junit results from `currentBuild` within a Stage block. With the help of @S.Richmond I was able to understand how the pipeline works and what was triggering the Exception.Then I moved the `currentBuild` code to outside of the pipeline block into a `@NonCPS` independent method. Start working immediately without exceptions. (I know I'm not supposed to still want to thank @S.Richmond for the very good explanation)
So I moved the

Comment: thanks, this clue "Try unsetting your object var " save my day. In my case I just set the variable to null after use it.

Comment: @byOnti it's not a solution for every case, it depends how you want to use the variable. E.g. if you just try to `echo` it (e.g. for testing) then unset it, the `echo` itself will not work, it will trigger the exception. It's better to avoid having such data in the first place, e.g. by using JsonSlurperClasic or Jenkins readJSON step (which can read from a string as well as from a file)

Answer (score 184):

Use `JsonSlurperClassic` instead.

Since Groovy 2.3 (*note: Jenkins 2.7.1 uses Groovy 2.4.7*) `JsonSlurper` returns `LazyMap` instead of `HashMap`. This makes new implementation of `JsonSlurper` **not** thread safe and **not** serializable. This makes it unusable outside of @NonDSL functions in pipeline DSL scripts.

However you can fall-back to `groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic` which supports old [behavior](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6934) and could be safely used within pipeline scripts.

## Example

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic 


@NonCPS
def jsonParse(def json) {
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}

node('master') {
    def config =  jsonParse(readFile("config.json"))

    def db = config["database"]["address"]
    ...
}
```

ps. You still will need to approve `JsonSlurperClassic` before it could be called.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to approve `JsonSlurperClassic`?

Comment: Jenkins administrator will need to navigate to Manage Jenkins » In-process Script Approval.

Comment: Unfortunately I only get `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic`

Comment: JsonSluperClassic.. This name tells a lot about current state of software development

Comment: JsonSluperClassic() messes up with the order of Json elements...

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. You saved a lot of time of mine. This solution works like a charm in my jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Now it get `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic`. I'm guessing this means that `JsonSlurperClassic()` is now defunct for exactly the same reason as `JsonSlurper()`?

Comment: @pullmyteeth Maybe don't keep a reference to the slurper. I.e. don't assign it to a variable, instead just instantiate and immediately call it `final obj = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonText)`. I guess this will help. But if not, put the whole code inside a NonCPS-annotated helper function `@NonCPS parseJSON(String text) { return new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(text) }`

Answer (score 20):

**EDIT:** As pointed out by [@Sunvic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3318642/sunvic) in the comments, the below solution does not work as-is for JSON Arrays.

I dealt with this by using `JsonSlurper` and then creating a new `HashMap` from the lazy results. `HashMap` is `Serializable`.

I believe that this required whitelisting of both the `new HashMap(Map)` and the `JsonSlurper`.

```
@NonCPS
def parseJsonText(String jsonText) {
  final slurper = new JsonSlurper()
  return new HashMap<>(slurper.parseText(jsonText))
}
```

Overall, I would recommend just using the [**Pipeline Utility Steps** plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps), as it has a [`readJSON` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) that can support either files in the workspace or text.

Comment: Didn't work me - kept getting an error `Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.HashMap(java.util.ArrayList)`. Documentation suggests it should spit out a list or a map - how do you configure to return a map?

Comment: @Sunvic Good catch, the data we have been parsing are always objects, never JSON arrays. Are you trying to parse a JSON array?

Comment: Ah yes, it's a JSON array, that'll be it.

Comment: Both this answer and below, on Jenkins, raised an RejectedEception because Jenkins runs groovy in sandbox env

Comment: @yiwen I mentioned that it requires administrator whitelisting, but maybe the answer could be clarified as to what that means?

Comment: The thing is when using `HashMap` or `JsonSlurperClassic`. The Jenkins in-process approval UI is supposed to ask an admin if you approve the use of them. But the UI didn't display that so there is no way to approve it

Answer (score 16):

I want to upvote one of the answer: I would recommend just using the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin, as it has a readJSON step that can support either files in the workspace or text: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

```
script{
  def foo_json = sh(returnStdout:true, script: "aws --output json XXX").trim()
  def foo = readJSON text: foo_json
}
```

This does NOT require any whitelisting or additional stuff.

Comment: What if your JSON doesn't come from a file? In my case I use httpRequest to work with Bitbucket Server REST API, the responses are in JSON format.

Comment: readJSON text: foo_json, "foo_json" is a string variable

Comment: Oh yeah, this works brilliantly. There's also an option for it `readPojo: true`, without it some strings looked a bit funny when printed for debug (but otherwise the code seemed to work fine). The only con I found is that in unit tests (I'm using JenkinsPipelineUnit) steps like `readJSON` have to be mocked, I just added a (not-so-)mock function that uses `JsonSlurper` to parse the JSON - this made the tests pass.

Answer (score 11):

This is the detailed answer that was asked for.

The unset worked for me:

```
String res = sh(script: "curl --header 'X-Vault-Token: ${token}' --request POST --data '${payload}' ${url}", returnStdout: true)
def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(res)
String value1 = response.data.value1
String value2 = response.data.value2

// unset response because it's not serializable and Jenkins throws NotSerializableException.
response = null
```

I read the values from the parsed response and when I don't need the object anymore I unset it.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly more generalized form of the answer from @mkobit which would allow decoding of arrays as well as maps would be:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

@NonCPS
def parseJsonText(String json) {
  def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
  if(object instanceof groovy.json.internal.LazyMap) {
      return new HashMap<>(object)
  }
  return object
}
```

NOTE: Be aware that this will only convert the top level LazyMap object to a HashMap. Any nested LazyMap objects will still be there and continue to cause issues with Jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function to convert LazyMap to a regular LinkedHashMap (it will keep the order of original data):

```
LinkedHashMap nonLazyMap (Map lazyMap) {
    LinkedHashMap res = new LinkedHashMap()
    lazyMap.each { key, value ->
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            res.put (key, nonLazyMap(value))
        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            res.put (key, value.stream().map { it instanceof Map ? nonLazyMap(it) : it }.collect(Collectors.toList()))
        } else {
            res.put (key, value)
        }
    }
    return res
}

... 

LazyMap lazyMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText (jsonText)
Map serializableMap = nonLazyMap(lazyMap);
```

or better use a readJSON step as noticed in earlier comments:

```
Map serializableMap = readJSON text: jsonText
```

Answer (score 3):

According to best practices posted on Jenkins blog ([Pipeline scalability best practice](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/)), it is **strongly recommended to use command-line tools or scripts** for this kind of work :

> *Gotcha: especially avoid Pipeline XML or JSON parsing using Groovy’s
>   XmlSlurper and JsonSlurper! Strongly prefer command-line tools or
>   scripts.*
>
> i. The Groovy implementations are complex and as a result more brittle in Pipeline use.
>
> ii. XmlSlurper and JsonSlurper can carry a high memory and CPU cost in pipelines
>
> iii. xmllint and xmlstartlet are command-line tools offering XML extraction via xpath
>
> iv. jq offers the same functionality for JSON
>
> v. These extraction tools may be coupled to curl or wget for fetching information from an HTTP API

Thus, it explains why most solutions proposed on this page are blocked by default by Jenkins security script plugin's sandbox.

The language philosophy of Groovy is closer to Bash than Python or Java. Also, it means it's not natural to do complex and heavy work in native Groovy.

Given that, I personally decided to use the following :

```
sh('jq <filters_and_options> file.json')
```

See [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) and [Select objects with jq stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq) for more help.

This is a bit counter intuitive because Groovy provides many generic methods that are not in the default whitelist.

If you decide to use Groovy language anyway for most of your work, with sandbox enabled and clean (which is not easy because not natural), I recommend you to check the whitelists for your security script plugin's version to know what are your possibilities : [Script security plugin whitelists](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists)

Answer (score 2):

The way pipeline plugin has been implemented has quite serious implications for non-trivial Groovy code. This link explains how to avoid possible problems: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables

In your specific case I'd consider adding `@NonCPS` annotation to `slurpJSON` and returning map-of-maps instead of JSON object. Not only the code looks cleaner, but it's also more efficient, especially if that JSON is complex.

Answer (score 1):

The other ideas in this post were helpful, but not quite all I was looking for - so I extracted the parts that fit my need and added some of my own magix...

```
def jsonSlurpLaxWithoutSerializationTroubles(String jsonText)
{
    return new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(
        new JsonBuilder(
            new JsonSlurper()
                .setType(JsonParserType.LAX)
                .parseText(jsonText)
        )
        .toString()
    )
}
```

Yes, as I noted in my own git commit of the code, *"Wildly-ineffecient, but tiny coefficient: JSON slurp solution"* (which I'm okay with for this purpose).
The aspects I needed to solve:

1. Completely get away from the `java.io.NotSerializableException` problem, even when the JSON text defines nested containers
2. Work for both map and array containers
3. Support LAX parsing (the most important part, for my situation)
4. Easy to implement (even with the awkward nested constructors that obviate `@NonCPS`)

Answer (score 1):

Noob mistake on my part. Moved someones code from a old pipeline plugin, jenkins 1.6? to a server running the latest 2.x jenkins.

Failed for this reason: "java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.IntRange"
I kept reading and reading this post multiple times for the above error.
Realized:
for (num in 1..numSlaves) {
IntRange - non-serializable object type.

Rewrote in simple form:
for (num = 1; num <= numSlaves; num++)

All is good with the world.

I do not use java or groovy very often.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found more easy way in [off docs for Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-grep)

**Work example**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic 


@NonCPS
def jsonParse(def json) {
    new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}

@NonCPS
def jobs(list) {
    list
        .grep { it.value == true  }
        .collect { [ name : it.key.toString(),
                      branch : it.value.toString() ] }

}

node {
    def params = jsonParse(env.choice_app)
    def forBuild = jobs(params)
}
```

> Due to limitations in Workflow - i.e., [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481) - it's not really possible to use Groovy closures or syntax that depends on closures, so you can't > do the Groovy standard of using .collectEntries on a list and generating the steps as values for the resulting entries. You also can't use the standard > Java syntax for For loops - i.e., "for (String s: strings)" - and instead have to use old school counter-based for loops.

Comment: Would recommend to use Jenkins pipeline step readJSON instead - find more info [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use JsonSlupurClassic, here a simple way to transform LazyMap to LinkedHashMap.

```
def deserialize(String jsonStr) {
    def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)
    if (obj instanceof Map) {
        return cloneMap(obj)
    } else if (obj instanceof List) {
        return cloneList(obj)
    } else {
        return obj
    }
    return
}

def cloneMap(Map map) {
    def res = [:]
    map.each {e ->
        def key = e.getKey()
        def value = e.getValue()
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            res.put(key, cloneMap(value))
        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            res.put(key, cloneList(value))
        } else {
            res.put(key, value)
        }
    }
    return res
}

def cloneList(List list) {
    def res = []
    list.each {i ->
        if (i instanceof List) {
            res.add(cloneList(i))
        } else if (i instanceof Map) {
            res.add(cloneMap(i))
        } else {
            res.add(i)
        }
    }
    return res
}
```