# Jenkins Workflow java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap in Closure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've got the following function in a workflow script that results in the error  `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`

```
def getParentTagForCurrentBranch(appWorkspace) {

   def parentTag = null

   dir("${appWorkspace.getPath()}") {

      parentTag = bat(script:"git describe --abbrev=0 --tags", returnStdout:true)
   }

   return parentTag
}
```

What I don't understand about the error is where I am using a LazyMap?

I've tried quite a few different variations of this block but all result in the error, I've also tried using the `@NonCPS` but that just results in the whole method being skipped.

Can anyone help me understand why this produces the error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't parsing JSON somewhere else in the workflow?

Comment: If you can find where the JSON parsing is happening, this answer to another question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38439681/4142522 . I've found it to be the simplest way to work around the deficiencies of the default JsonSlurper without adding new dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks the problem was with `JsonSlurper`switching to `JsonSlurperClassic`did the trick as mentioned here [Jenkins Pipeline NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap/38439681#38439681)

Comment: So, FYI, I saw this today: `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic`

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to prevent this?  I just saw the same error, and I'm really confused.  I was under the impression that using groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic is the recommended solution for avoiding the Jenkins object serialization issue.  So, if it's throwing a java.io.NotSerializableException on that class, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I also encountered this issue yesterday and fixed it by using readJSON instead of JsonSlurperClassic. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: @challett This should be actually the answer. Could you post it as one? I don't want to take your credits.