# Bitbucket Team/Project - Get BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD in Pipeline Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I'm setting up a new bitbucket server with a webhook trigger that builds job in Jenkins

Bitbucket Team/Project run Pipeline Jenkinsfile.
In Jenkinsfile I should know the action that is done in bitbucket server(new branch/pull request ..)

So I'm trying to get ${BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD}, but got an exception

```
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD 
for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at  
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
```

Is someone can help me to understand why bitbucket doesn't inject the payload to Jenkins job?

Comment: Did you solve it in the end?

Comment: Is this SO answer along the lines of what you're looking for? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700935/5098460