# Jenkins - Having issues with PostBuild Email notifications

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

Trying to use the following piece of code to trigger email notifications for a multi-branch pipeline job:

```
1    def emailNotification() {
2        def to = emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
3                                     [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
4                                     [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']])
5       
6       //def to = "firstname.lastname@domain.com"                               
7        //String currentResult = currentBuild.result
8       String currentResult = manager.build.getResult()
9       echo "CurrentResult1=${currentResult}"
10      echo "CurrentResult2=${manager.build.getResult()}"
11      echo "CurrentResult3=${manager.build.result}"
12        String previousResult = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result
13    
14        def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
15        // E.g. 'started by user', 'triggered by scm change'
16        def cause = null
17        if (!causes.isEmpty()) {
18            cause = causes[0].getShortDescription()
19        }
20    
21        // Ensure we don't keep a list of causes, or we get
22        // "java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause"
23        // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37897833/509706
25        causes = null
26    
27        String subject = "${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}: ${currentResult}"
28    
29        String body = """
30                      <p>Triggered by: <b>${cause}</b></p>
31    
32                      <p>Last build result: <b>${previousResult}</b></p>
33    
34    
35                      <p>Build <b>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</b> ran on <b>${env.NODE_NAME}</b> and terminated with <b>${currentResult}</b>.
36                      </p>
37    
38                      <p>See: <a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.BUILD_URL}</a></p>
39    
40                      """
41    
42        String log = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(40).join('\n')
43        if (currentBuild != 'SUCCESS') {
44            body = body + """
45                          <h2>Last lines of output</h2>
46                          <pre>${log}</pre>
47                          """
48        }
49    
50        if (to != null && !to.isEmpty()) {
51            // Email on any failures, and on first success.
52            if (currentResult != 'SUCCESS' || currentResult != previousResult) {
53                mail to: to, subject: subject, body: body, mimeType: "text/html"
54            }
55            echo 'Sent email notification'
56        }
57    }
```

Now, the problems that I'm facing:

1. `def to = emailextrecipients...` is not working. I found [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43386) and [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9016) Jenkins Jira issues that this may be the causes, but no workaround. Although it seems weird that if the build is started manually, say by me a user authenticated through Github Oauth, the mail can be sent. If the Github is starting the build through the webhook, I'm getting this in the Jenkins logs:

> Not sending mail to user firstname.lastname@domain.com with no
>   permission to view

2. The second issue that I'm seeing is with the PostBuild email trigger.
   The Pipeline looks like this:

   ```
   def emailNotification() {
       //the one from above
   }
   try {
      stage('Stage1') {
          /*
          creating multiple nodes based on an array provided
          each node will execute:
          checkout scm
          buildSolution() //custom method defined
          */
          parallel <stuff_above>
      }
      stage('Stage2') {
          //do other stuff
          parallel <other_stuff_above>
       }
   } finally {
       emailNotification()
   }
   ```

The echoes from above (rows 9-11) are all showing `null`

CurrentResult1=null

CurrentResult2=null

CurrentResult3=null

Using `currentBuild.currentResult` will show me only `SUCCESS` or `FAILED`, but not `UNSTABLE`, in case some of the tests failed.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build status is null until something sets it or until the job finishes. Are you using any unit test steps that would cause the build to be unstable?

You don't need to use `emailextrecipients` instead use.

```
emailext body: body, mimeType: 'text/html', recipientProviders: [
  [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], 
  [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], 
  [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], subject: subject
```

> Not sending mail to user firstname.lastname@domain.com with no
>   permission to view

Means that either no jenkins user has this email address associated or the user it is associated with does not have permission to the job

Also for causes put that logic inside a different function and add `@NonCPS` annotation which will stop jenkins trying to serialise state while that function is running, as you currently have it there is a small chance it will still break with that exception, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38439681/963402