# use same properties in multiple Jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have choice-properties in my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
properties(
[parameters([
    choice(choices: ["app1", "app2"].join("\n"),
        description: 'global parameter', 
        name: 'globalParam'),
    choice(choices: ["foo", "bar", "baz"].join("\n"),
        description: 'job-specific parameter', 
        name: 'localParam')
    ])
]
)
```

This works, but I have multiple jobs (=multiple Jenkisnfiles) which all use the same array of `globalParam`, so when I want to add another choice (e.g. `'app3'`), I have to update **every** Jenkinsfile.

Is there a way to *share* such global parameter between multiple Jenkinsfiles?

In fact, there are also some other "global values" used in multiple Jenkinsfiles, so I already thought about using one global *YAML*-file to store those values - so I can use `readYAML` inside my `node{}`-block to fill my variables. But I don't know if/how I can use this yaml inside my `properties()`-block.

**Edit1:**
What I also tried:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
def myyaml = new Yaml().load(new FileReader('../../properties.yml'))
properties( ... )
```

But therefore I get

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

**Edit2:**
Based on @herm s suggestion, I tried to use the library plugin:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic;

def propsText = libraryResource 'my/lib/properties.json'
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
def properties = jsonSlurper.parseText(propsText)
def jobEnv = 'release'

properties(
[parameters([
    choice(choices: properties.params.modules.keySet().join("\n"),
        description: properties.props.module.description[jobEnv], 
        name: 'globalParam'),
    choice(choices: ["foo", "bar", "baz"].join("\n"),
        description: 'job-specific parameter', 
        name: 'localParam')
    ])
]
)
```

I can see the correct choice parameter in my Jenkins UI!
[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap), I approved JsonSlurperClassic.
But the job still fails - without error message (and no pending approvals).
So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it works:

I added a library in my `vars` folder:

```
// vars/jsonParse.groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic;

@NonCPS
def call(def json) {
    return new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(json)
}
```

My json-file is located at `resources/some/project/properties.json`

And my Jenkinsfile:

```
def propsText = libraryResource 'some/project/properties.json'
def properties = jsonParse(propsText)
def jobEnv = 'release'

properties(
[parameters([
    choice(choices: properties.params.modules.keySet().join("\n"),
        description: properties.props.module.description[jobEnv], 
        name: 'globalParam'),
    choice(choices: ["foo", "bar", "baz"].join("\n"),
        description: 'job-specific parameter', 
        name: 'localParam')
    ])
]
)
```

---

Edit:

Sadly, I couldn't manage to solve this for a `Declarative Pipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the global shared libraries plugin for that and have those parameters in a library

Comment: Thank you! Good hint, but my job still fails. See my edit.