# Issue with XmlSlurper

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I need to read data from 2 xml files. I have the following pipeline script:

```
            def targetServerConfigFileContent = readFile file: 'apiproxy/targets/default.xml'               
            def xmlObject1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(targetServerConfigFileContent);

            echo "-------------"
            existingTargetServerName = xmlObject1.HTTPTargetConnection.LoadBalancer.Server.'@name';

            echo "existingTargetServerName::${existingTargetServerName}"

            targetServerConfigFileContent = null;
            xmlObject1 = null;

            def proxyConfigFileContent = readFile file: 'apiproxy/'+ proxyName + '.xml'
            def xmlObject = new XmlSlurper().parseText(proxyConfigFileContent);

            existingProxyName = xmlObject.'@name'
            existingBasePath = xmlObject.Basepaths              
            existingProxyDesc = xmlObject.Description

            echo "existingProxyName::${existingProxyName}"
            echo "existingProxyDesc::${existingProxyDesc}"
            echo "existingBasePath::${existingBasePath}"

            proxyConfigFileContent = null;
            xmlObject = null;
```

The moment, I start reading the second file with code, it started throwing the exception.

```
def proxyConfigFileContent = readFile file: 'apiproxy/'+ proxyName + '.xml'
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {message=java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes} for EchoStep(message: String):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class
>   java.lang.String but received class java.io.NotSerializableException

Please let me know what was the wrong with the code.

Comment: is this scripted or declarative?

Comment: It is scripted.

Comment: I got it resolved by having the file read operations one after another.           **def targetServerConfigFileContent = readFile file: 'apiproxy/targets/default.xml'  
    def proxyConfigFileContent = readFile file: 'apiproxy/'+ proxyName + '.xml'**

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50146898/4279361 . If if it works right now it will fail to work in the future. You cannot safetly use any object inside Jenkins Pipeline CPS code which is not serializable - and `XmlSlurper` isn't..

Comment: Joerg S  Thank you for the suggestion. I will change the logic as per the link shared. In fact, I tried @NonCPS even before posting my problem here. I will check again and  let you know.