# How could I merge 2 json into one? do I need to merge them as strings?

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here is my code for merging 2 jsons into one... Is there a better way?

> Expected behaviour is to get a 'big json' with sum of 'entry jsons' and no
>   "type-XX" overlaps, and keeping the longest 'rc[ ]' list.

```
def json_src1 = '''
{
      "branch": {
                  "type-0.2": {
                      "version": "0.2",
                      "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                       }
              }
}
'''
def json_src2 = '''
{
      "branch": {
                  "type-0.3": {
                      "version": "0.3",
                      "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                      }
              }
}
'''

def concatenateJsons(json_src1, json_src2){
    def json = json_src1 + json_src2
    return json
}
```

To change strings to json objects:

```
json_src1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_src1)
json_src2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_src2)
```

To concatenate

```
json = concatenateJsons(json_src1, json_src2)
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(json))
```

Expected result:

```
{
"branch": {
           "type-0.2": {
           "version": "0.2",
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                       }

           "type-0.3": {
           "version": "0.3",
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                      }          
          }
}
```

> P.S I am losing order of elements inside of Json after merge for no obvious reason :
>   (`"version": "0.3"` moves to the bottom in type-03 {}:

Instead of:

```
{
"branch": {
           "type-0.2": {
           "version": "0.2",
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                       }

           "type-0.3": {
           "version": "0.3",
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                      }          
          }
}
```

I am getting

```
{
"branch": {
           "type-0.2": {
           "version": "0.2",
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]"
                       }

           "type-0.3": {
           "rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]",
            "version": "0.3"
                      }          
          }
}
```

Comment: please show the expected result.

Comment: expected result added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest thing you can do is to change the `concatenateJsons` function

```
def concatenateJsons(json_src1, json_src2){
    def json = [branch: json_src1.branch + json_src2.branch]
    return json
}
```

groovy not doing deep merge of parsed jsons it merges only root objects.

so, to merge content of branches just sum `branch` from each json

> Note: if both json1 and json2 has the same `type-X.Y` then second overlaps content of first one.

Comment: I got to the same conclusion by trial and error. There is one side effect though. I am losing order of the merged elements. For instance `"version": "0.3"` and   `"rc": "[17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]" ` got switched over. How could I ensure that `version` stays on top?

Comment: Could you modify example of source and output jsons to the question, so I could understand it better.

Comment: please see update in the question - for the example of switched order (`"version": "0.3"` goes to bottom)

Comment: there was issue in some old versions of groovy. normally it's not a problem because according to json specification order of keys in object has no meaning. if it's important for you - you could update groovy version or try other parser like gson...

Comment: I had troubles with JsonSlurper() and CPS errors in jenkins, so I have used JsonSlurperClassic()... which presumably is older? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap

Comment: Classic definitely has this issue. If you in pipeline - there is a native step to read json: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace