# Creating dynamic stages in jenkins pipeline fails on first loop execution?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jsonslurper

This is the pipeline I have created for processing a json from an API. However when I run this it fails after the first loop.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
pipeline {
agent none

stages {
    stage('Query Pull Requests'){
        steps{
            script {
                def response =  httpRequest authentication: 'BitbucketAuth', url: "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/repo-name/pullrequests"
                echo "Status: ${response.status}"
                def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
                def pullrequests = json.values;
                for (int i = 0; i < pullrequests.size(); i++) {
                    stage("Processing Pull Request ID : ${pullrequests[i].id}"){
                        echo "${pullrequests[i].source.branch.name}"
                        echo "${pullrequests[i].destination.branch.name}"
                        echo "${pullrequests[i].destination.repository.full_name}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[This is the error I am getting](https://pastebin.com/TcNdKP5c)

Jenkins ver. 2.107

Comment: Kindly update the error in the question. Please refrain from adding any link unless for a code hosted in git :)

Comment: When I add it in the question itself I get "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to unset the "**json**" variable to null once you do not need that variable anymore:-

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def pullrequests = json.values;
for (int i = 0; i < pullrequests.size(); i++) {
  stage("Processing Pull Request ID : ${pullrequests[i].id}"){
  echo "${pullrequests[i].source.branch.name}"
  echo "${pullrequests[i].destination.branch.name}"
  echo "${pullrequests[i].destination.repository.full_name}"
}

// unset response because it's not serializable and Jenkins throws NotSerializableException.
json = null
```

For more information follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap)