# Attempting a loop of http requests in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm attempting to complete a loop of http requests in a Jenkins pipeline. Any time I run the job, it looks like the first request is initiated but it doesn't complete and I get the below error after: `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        script {
            def testCases = new JsonSlurper().parseText(env.JIRA_TEST_CASES)
            for (issue in testCases.issues) {
                httpRequest contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', httpMode: 'POST', url: url, requestBody: createBody(issue.key), authentication: auth, consoleLogResponseBody: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding testCases = null after the forloop. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap