# Gerrit review - Applying verified label for current patchset returns java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

Tags: groovy, gerrit

I am trying to set the verified label of a particular patchset to either -1 or +1 depending on the stage of a spinnaker job. It will be set to -1 to signify it hasn't been through the testing stage, and then +1 after it passes testing.

To do this, I am looking at using this: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html

From this documentation, it is required to specify either the commit ID or the change number plus a patch set.

The following command does work: `sh "ssh -p $GERRIT_PORT $GERRIT_SERVER gerrit review --verified -1 --project $GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_COMMIT_ID"` (`GERRIT_COMMIT_ID` is something I am retrieving and defining myself, using JsonSlurper with `gerrit query` instead of `gerrit review`)

However, the following command does not work:  `sh "ssh -p $GERRIT_PORT $GERRIT_SERVER gerrit review --verified -1 --project $GERRIT_PROJECT $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$CURRENT_PATCHSET"` (`CURRENT_PATCHSET` is something I am retrieving and defining myself, using JsonSlurper with `gerrit query` instead of `gerrit review`)

I get the following error when the command is ran through a Jenkins build:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@9368746
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@5d10e015
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@927cbc7
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@5f2e8a0f
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3cd000c0
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3cd000c0
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:163)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.writeObject(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor764.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:163)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$1(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:537)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:520)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:444)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:279)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have not been able to find much online in regards to the above error. Anything related to `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` doesn't seem applicable to my situation.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Does the first result in Google not help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864542/jenkins-pipeline-notserializableexception-groovy-json-internal-lazymap